# I had moved Magento from old server to Newser and Export products my old server to import my new server

Tags: magento-1.9, import, image, export, server-setup

Move to a media file old server to new server but product image not showing. 
Please help me

Comment: did you "reimport" all your products?

Comment: I moved all products, but not showing product images front-end and back-end.

Comment: What do you mean by "moved them"? Did you export them in a csv and then imported this csv in your new server?

Comment: Sorry, imported csv in my new server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import products from a csv that have 'image','small_image' and/or 'thumbnail' and you expect the image to be imported, then you need to have the image file in /media/import.

Examples

1. You have a file with

sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
sku1,/product1.jpg,/product1.jpg,/product1.jpg

Then you need to have the file /media/import/product1.jpg

2. You have a file with

sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
sku1,/p/r/product1.jpg,/p/r/product1.jpg,/p/r/product1.jpg

Then you need to have the file /media/import/p/r/product1.jpg